# Returning a List correctly

Tags: android, xml, list, oop

How do I return a List correctly?

I am programming an App with OSMdroid and I want to use the variables "longitude" and "latitude" of the class "Place"(on the bottom of this Post) to ultimately use them in the "onPostExecute" method, right where I set the "PLACEHOLDERS".

Android Studio wants me to alter the line "return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);", which executes the code below, but I dont know how exactly (The methods below are in the same class).

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            //Here I want to recieve the list
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.xml_error);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Place> result) {

        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(17);
        //Here I want to use the latitude and longitude variables of the List
        GeoPoint myLocation = new GeoPoint(PLACEHOLDER(latitude), PLACEHOLDER(longitude)); 
        mapController.animateTo(myLocation);

    }
}
```

This is where I recieve the list for the first time:

```
private List<Place> loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;  // Instantiate the parser
    XMLParser XMLParser = new XMLParser();
    List<Place> places = null; 

    try {
        stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        places = XMLParser.parse(stream);  // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    return places;
}
```

This is my Place class:

```
public class Place {
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;
    private String place_id;

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getPlace_id() {
        return place_id;
    }
    public void setPlace_id(String place_id) {this.place_id = place_id;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: " + place_id + "\n" + "Longitude: " + longitude + "\n" + "Latitude: " + latitude;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three parametric types of the `AsyncTask` are `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`

(See the [AsyncTask documentation](http://AsyncTask%3CParams,%20Progress,%20Result%3E))

If you want to have a `List<Place>` as a result, you must replace

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

with

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Place>> {
```

Your `doInBackground()` method must then return a `List<Place>` instead of a `String`. The line where you call `loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0])` will then work since `loadXmlFromNetwork()` do returns a `List<Place>`, but the two other return lines in your catches clauses won't compile anymore since they return `String`. You must change them, and return `null`, for example.

**Edit:** As @Code-Apprentice said, the exception shouldn't just be ignored. You could use boolean flags in order to check them later.

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Place>> {
    private boolean mConnectionError;
    private boolean mXMLError;

    @Override
    protected List<Place> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            //Here I want to recieve the list
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mConnectionError = true;
            return null;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            mXMLError = true;
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Place> result) {

        if (result != null) {
            MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
            IMapController mapController = map.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(17);
            //Here I want to use the latitude and longitude variables of the List
            GeoPoint myLocation = new GeoPoint(PLACEHOLDER(latitude), PLACEHOLDER(longitude)); 
            mapController.animateTo(myLocation);

        } else {
            // An error happened, check mConnectionError and
            // mXMLError in order to display an error message.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer can made more complete by also including suggestions for displaying an error message rather than just ignoring the exceptions.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The error seems to be gone now, but I am struggling to get the value out of the list where my PLACEHOLDERS are right now. I thought i could get them with "result(latitude)", but that doesnt seem to work. Nit: Also I dont understand your comment on the catches clauses. Could you explain them further please?

Comment: @Glave You should be able to access the values with `result.get(n).getLatitude()`, be sure to check that `result != null` and `n < result.size()`

Comment: It finally works. Thank you so much. You have no idea how important this was for my future!

Comment: You're welcome @Glave.

About the catches clauses, I was saying that you can't return a `String` value (`getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error)` is a `String` type) since the `doInBackground()` method is supposed to return a `List<Place>`, that's why I suggested to return `null` instead, and manage the error messages in another way.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I dont understand what you mean, because I was never confronted with exceptions. I implemented the changes you suggested. It works now. But only if the XML-file is not empty. If the XML is empty, because a place like this doesnt exist in the world (e.g. "dnsgojnsdd") or I hit the Send-Button with typing anything at all the App crashes. I guess the reason for that is the exact same thing you are talking about. Do you have any idea how should handle this? I tried if(stream!=null) {places = XMLParser.parse(stream);} in the try block of "loadXmlFromNetwork". App still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to change

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

to

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Place>>
```

The last parameter for `AsyncTask` is the result type. You will need a different way to communicate error situations. For example you can add some boolean fields to use as flags and appropriate gettters to access them. Besides, the AsyncTask should not be responsible for error messages displayed in the UI. This violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Also i think XMLParser  throws, so he needs not only finnaly but catch as well

Comment: @X3Btel The exceptions are declared in the throws clause and propagated up the call stack. Then they are caught in doInBackground().

Comment: I marked Nits answer as correct, but since its more or less the same answer and its so rare I actually get any answers to my questions I want to thank you anyway for give a damn.

Comment: @Glave No problem. His answer is much more detailed. When you have enough rep, you can up vote both of our answers to show your appreciation.